# Discord.py How do I get the status of a user and send a message when it changes?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want the bot to know when a member changes their status and want to send a message in #general. I've seen many posts about on_presence_update() being deprecated. I can't think of another method. I have intents on.

```
@client.event
async def on_presence_update(before: discord.Member, after: discord.Member):
    if after.id == my_Member_id:
        print('{} changed status to {}'.format(
            after.display_name,
            after.status
        ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if `before.status != after.status`?

By the way, I think `on_presence_update()` is deprecated like you said. The **new one** is `on_member_update()`

Comment: I tried using it and bot started but it seems that it is not able to detect the update